# Cannot index string with string "name"

Tags: bash, devops, jq, github-api

I have a script that imports bunch of github info as .tf files using jq

```
function get_team_repos() {
    log "Importing team repositories..." "INFO"
    for PAGE in $(limit_team_pagination); do

        for i in $(curl --silent -s -u "$USERNAME:$GITHUB_TOKEN" "${API_URL_PREFIX}/orgs/$ORG/teams/${TEAM_ID}/repos?page=${PAGE}&per_page=100" | jq -M -r 'sort_by(.name) | .[] | .name'); do
            TERRAFORM_TEAM_REPO_NAME=$(echo "${i}" | tr "." "-")
            log "Team repo: $TERRAFORM_TEAM_REPO_NAME" "INFO"
            TEAM_NAME=$(curl --silent -s -u "$USERNAME:$GITHUB_TOKEN" "${API_URL_PREFIX}/orgs/$ORG/teams" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" | jq -M -r 'sort_by(.name) | .[] | .name' | tr " " "_" | tr "/" "_")
            log "Working on $TEAM_NAME" "INFO"
            PERMS_PAYLOAD=$(curl --silent -s -u "$USERNAME:$GITHUB_TOKEN" "${API_URL_PREFIX}/orgs/${ORG}/teams/${TEAM_ID}/repos" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.repository+json")
            ADMIN_PERMS=$(echo "$PERMS_PAYLOAD" | jq -M -r .permissions.admin)
            PUSH_PERMS=$(echo "$PERMS_PAYLOAD" | jq -M -r .permissions.push)
            PULL_PERMS=$(echo "$PERMS_PAYLOAD" | jq -M -r .permissions.pull)

            if [[ "${ADMIN_PERMS}" == "true" ]]; then
                cat >>"github-teams-${TEAM_NAME}.tf" <<EOF
```

Which prompts the following error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot index string with string "name"
╷
│ Error: Attribute name required
│ 
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: github_team_repository.-
│ 
│ Dot must be followed by attribute name.
╵
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Which jq line is causing the problem, and can you give us a sample of the input to that jq statement? Execute `curl --silent -s -u "$USERNAME:$GITHUB_TOKEN" "${API_URL_PREFIX}/orgs/$ORG/teams/${TEAM_ID}/repos?page=${PAGE}&per_page=100"` with the right env and see what happens.

Comment: Actually, it was my bad, the jq statement appears to be fine, terraform doesn't like '.' in the resources names so i had to add this   `TERRAFORM_TEAM_REPO_NAME=$(echo "${i}" | tr "." "-")`

the curl in questions prompts the following:

`{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}`

Comment: it would appear that the api call is outdated, my bad, i'd have to see how the new api looks like before i continue further, thanks

Comment: I thought it might be something like that.

Comment: However, the error persists, if i execute this curl:

`curl --silent -s -u "$USERNAME:$GITHUB_TOKEN" "${API_URL_PREFIX}/orgs/$ORG/teams/${TEAM_ID}/repos?page=${PAGE}&per_page=100" | jq -M -r 'sort_by(.name) | .[] | .name'`

I'm prompted with the following error:
jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot index string with string "name"

Comment: And what is the output of the curl without the jq bit?

Answer (score 0):

It means it can not find the key. Check that your `query` matches the structure of the `json` document.